# PHP: Sum of Array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a difficulty getting the sum of the array.
Since I have a different formula, I can't use the codeigniter's function `select_sum()`

The code below is my attempt, but I have failed to make it functional.

```
$this->db->where('request_id', $this->input->post('request_id'));  
              $this->db->join('medical_request_items', 'items.item_id=medical_request_items.item_id');                  
              $quer2 = $this->db->get('items');

                    foreach ($quer2->result() as $row) {                            


                         $lol = (($row->item_quantity * $row->item_retailprice) - ($row->item_quantity * $row->discount) - ($row->item_quantity * $row->philhealth) - ($row->item_quantity * $row->senior));

                    }


                    echo array_sum(array($lol));
```

Comment: The final `$lol` is not even an array. I'm pretty sure `array_sum` won't work.

Comment: I did it here `array_sum(array($lol))`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. And what did you get ?

Comment: it is only getting the value of the 1st item. it's not summing up the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your query and formula don't have any problems and work as they should. Declare `$lol` as an array before the loop

```
$lol = array();
```

In the loop

```
$lol = ((.....
```

should be

```
$lol[] = ((...
```

Then, you just echo the sum

```
 echo array_sum($lol);
```